# Trying to efficiently hollow out a sphere in minecraft (fabric modding, 1.16.5)

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to hollow out a sphere, I already achieved this however it is incredibly slow (A few seconds for a sphere with a radius of 5, a few minutes for a sphere with a radius of 100)

This is my code:

```java
BlockPos pos = player.getBlockPos();
int startX = pos.getX();
int startY = pos.getY();
int startZ = pos.getZ();

int squaredRadius = radius * radius;

int x1;
int y1;
int z1;
int flags = 2 | 8 | 16 | 32;
BlockPos.Mutable blockPos = new BlockPos.Mutable(0, 0, 0);
BlockState state = Blocks.AIR.getDefaultState();

for (int x = startX - radius; x < startX + radius; x++) {
    for (int y = Math.max(0, startY - radius), maxY2 = Math.min(255, startY + radius); y < maxY2; y++) {
        for (int z = startZ - radius; z < startZ + radius; z++) {
            x1 = x - startX;
            y1 = y - startY;
            z1 = z - startZ;
            if (x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 + z1 * z1 <= squaredRadius)
                world.setBlockState(blockPos.set(x, y, z), state, flags);
        }
    }
}
```

How could I speed this up? (Or is it already as fast as it can be?)

EDIT: For a 100 radius it takes roughly 8 minutes on my machine

Comment: For comparison, how fast on your computer is the `/fill` command to hollow out a cube of similar volume?

Comment: 10 ish minutes for the fill (the fill command has a max of 32k so I just remade the implementation with the same code)

Comment: In that case, doesn't it seem like your code is as fast as can be and that the slowness is just inherent to setting that many blocks in Minecraft?

Comment: Probably, made a mixin into the setBlockState and stopped further execution after the block was actually set if a flag was set, this does indeed work! It reduced it from 8 minutes to 3 (to be exact 3 minutes and 20.5 seconds), however I need to manually send the chunk updates to players

Comment: Yes, when you do one thing over and over there is likely to be a lot of overhead because every single block you set is going to do a block update, send to players, etc. It might even be fastest to directly access the chunk data and fill one chunk at a time and then send that chunk, and don't do block updates or anything else. This can cause slight problems (e.g. floating water) but it might be worth it for the speed.

Comment: Yep, Currently doing no block updates at all, there is a problem where chunks aren't sent but i just gotta resend the chunks to the players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I managed to fix it! What I did was make a mixin into `World#setBlockState(BlockPos, BlockState, int)` and check if the flags were some number I set (999 in my case), and if it where I canceled the method execution right after the block state was set, saving huge amounts of time when placing a lot of blocks. However, it did not send the chunks to the player so what you have to do is simply send all the chunks you changed to the player, I did this by storing all the chunks I changed and for each player in the world I sent a ChunkDataS2CPacket with the new chunk to the player, which fixed my problem entirely, it works like a charm :D

EDIT: It also does not do block updates/lighting updates